# performSegueWithIdentifier in an if statement causing app to crash using a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uicollectionviewcell, uistoryboardsegue

I have a UICollectionView and this method:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
```

Inside of this method, I have this statement:

```
switch indexPath.item {
case 7:
    switch boatTypeSelectedText {
    case "Royal Boat":
        if definitionSelectedText == "Used to carry the pharoah" {
            if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            }
        } else {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Game End", sender: self)
            gameOutcomeLabel.text = "You Lost on level \(selectLevelBoatMatchingGame.currentLevel)!"
        }
```

Note: `gameOutComeLabel` is part of the view controller that the segue should send to, but that view controller is the same class as the current one. In the `else` statement, I have created a `performSegueWithIdentifier` method. When this method is triggered, I get the following error in the console:

```
2014-12-18 16:52:39.908 SailingTheNile[31847:20249939] *** Assertion failure in -[SailingTheNile.BoatMatchingGame loadView], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UICollectionViewController.m:166
2014-12-18 16:52:39.912 SailingTheNile[31847:20249939] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] loaded the "83r-qs-tQG-view-Zwj-3W-sDw" nib but didn't get a UICollectionView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x002fd946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01cd9a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x002fd7da +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 138
    3   Foundation                          0x00770810 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 118
    4   UIKit                               0x012545a8 -[UICollectionViewController loadView] + 597
    5   UIKit                               0x00c67fef -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    6   UIKit                               0x00c68595 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    7   UIKit                               0x012db707 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 75
    8   UIKit                               0x00c3da81 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 113
    9   UIKit                               0x00c75a61 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 2102
    10  UIKit                               0x00c785d2 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 345
    11  UIKit                               0x00c78424 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 224
    12  UIKit                               0x01140a94 -[UIStoryboardPresentationSegue perform] + 117
    13  UIKit                               0x0112db49 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 217
    14  UIKit                               0x00c6a81c -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 72
    15  SailingTheNile                      0x00080207 _TFC14SailingTheNile16BoatMatchingGame14collectionViewfS0_FTCSo16UICollectionView24didSelectItemAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 14391
    16  SailingTheNile                      0x00081b99 _TToFC14SailingTheNile16BoatMatchingGame14collectionViewfS0_FTCSo16UICollectionView24didSelectItemAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 89
    17  UIKit                               0x012287e8 -[UICollectionView _selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 591
    18  UIKit                               0x01246022 -[UICollectionView _userSelectItemAtIndexPath:] + 191
    19  UIKit                               0x01246216 -[UICollectionView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 492
    20  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01cef7cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    21  UIKit                               0x00cc6254 forwardTouchMethod + 270
    22  UIKit                               0x00cc62c4 -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 31
    23  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01cef7cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    24  UIKit                               0x00cc6254 forwardTouchMethod + 270
    25  UIKit                               0x00cc62c4 -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 31
    26  UIKit                               0x00b6260a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
    27  UIKit                               0x00b630e5 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791
    28  UIKit                               0x00b28549 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    29  UIKit                               0x00b3837e _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
    30  UIKit                               0x00b0cb19 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x002211df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00216ced __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00216248 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00215bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x002159fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x02d0724f GSEventRunModal + 192
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x02d0708c GSEventRun + 104
    38  UIKit                               0x00b108b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    39  SailingTheNile                      0x0007546e top_level_code + 78
    40  SailingTheNile                      0x000754ab main + 43
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x030b1ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) 

How can I prevent this error from happening and the performSegueWithIdentifier method to work? Let me know if I need to provide any more code. Thanks for the support!
```

Comment: Have you double checked your segue identifier is typed correctly in both your `if` statement and `UIStoryboard`?

Comment: Yes, I just checked again and they are both the exact same. You don't have to put quotation marks around the identifier in the storyboard, right? @Freddy

Comment: The error looks like the segue is fine, but there's a problem with the next collection view controller. Have you done anything to it in the storyboard? Is the `view` outlet still connected?

Comment: Well, the next controller is actually a regular ViewController. The class that this method is in is of type UICollectionView. The ViewController that the segue is sending it to is also under this class. Should I make each the ViewController that the segue that is being sent to a different class? @jrturton

Comment: Why are you segueing to another instance of the same view controller? It seems if all you are you trying to do is update the game outcome label, that no segue is needed.

Comment: No, they are 2 different view controllers, just under the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in `prepareForSegue()`. You can do:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as YourViewControllerName
    destination.gameOutcomeLabel.text = "AnyText"
}
```

The text you want to display has to be "transported" with the sender or stored as a public variable.

Comment: I tried this, with the text I want to be displayed as a public var, and I get this error in the console: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)` on the line of `destination.gameOutcomeLabel.text = gameOutcomeText`. `gameOutcomeText` is the public variable I created.

Comment: Well actually this should work so there are two things: `gameOutcomeLabel`should be declared as `var gameOutcomeLabel: UILabel!` and the second question is: Are you using an `UINavigationController`? When yes I would modify the answer above.

Comment: On top of that you should watch out that `gameOutcomeText`is not optional. Otherwise you would have to use `= gameOutcomeText!`

Comment: Well I saw something else in your error message - the error did occur in `loadView()`: Do _not_ use _ever_ `loadView()`. Write all your code into `viewDidLoad()` - that's the only thing working in Swift

Comment: I am not using a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured it out using your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my second ViewController, I created an instance of my first ViewController:

```
class GameOutcome: UIViewController {
var boatMatchingGame: BoatMatchingGame!
```

Then, in my first ViewController I set the `prepareForSegue` method and I did this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let gameOutcome = segue.destinationViewController as GameOutcome
    gameOutcome.boatMatchingGame = self;
```

`boatMatchingGame` was the instance I set. Next, in the viewDidLoad I changed the text of the label by passing in the value of a `public var` I set.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    gameOutcomeLabel.text = gameOutcomeText
}
```

Thanks for anyone's support!